# Real Time sensor data from the Apple Watch during a Workout Session

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2, healthkit

Assuming I start a workoutsession on the apple watch is there a way to get say accelerator, distance or energy burnt or any other data that the Apple Watch sensor supports in real time even when the watch is sleep (screen is off).  If so what's the sample rate for this data being available.  Can I execute any code when I receive this data in those intervals while the watch is sleep. For example can I trigger a haptic notification when I receive the data although the watch screen is still off and while in the active workout session?

Comment: @Allan is correct. The data supplied by the apple watch sensors are not delivered in real time if the screen is off. Data may be collected while the screen is off, but it is only delivered to the app when the screen is on and your app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps on watchOS 2 do not run while the screen is off, even after starting a workout session. Your app can only process data while the screen is on.